# How to remove a view when the underlying model is removed

Tags: swiftui

I'm writing something along the lines of list/details views, where I have a list of items rendered on the main view. When the user clicks on an item, we show a details view of that item. I'm using a navigation stack. The code is simple enough. The gist of it is like this:

```
NavigationStack {
  List {
    ForEach(model.items) { item in
      NavigationLink {
        DetailsView(model: item)
      } label: {
        Text(item.name)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The list of items, however, can be changed by a background thread. E.g. polling a source from the Internet. When an item is removed, the change is reflected in the list view. But if the details view is on the top when it happens, how do I remove that view? It doesn't look like there's a way to get the topmost view (or any view, for that matter) of a

Comment: You can use [`NavigationStack(path:root:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationstack/init(path:root:)-3bt4q) to access the navigation state and pop back to the list when the items change.

Comment: Usually if Model is an `EnvironmentObject` every removed element from `model.items` should close the respective NavigationLink

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a bunch of ways to achieve that, for example, if the detail view can be notified, you can perform the correct action within it:

1. Define that you want to be notified about the `original model` changes in the `DetailsView` like:

```
struct DetailsView: View {
    let model: Item

    @EnvironmentObject var originalModel: Model //  The model that contains the `items` array
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss //  The action to dismiss this view if needed

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(model.name)
        }
        .onChange(of: originalModel.items) { oldValue, newValue in //  Observe for changes here
            if !newValue.contains(model) { dismiss() } //  Perform the needed action like `dismiis`
        } 
    }
}
```

<sub>Note that it would be wired for the user to pop to the parent unexpectedly but you can also handle the situation inside the observation like showing a banner or something</sub>

2. Pass in the original model as an `environmentObject` in the parent like:

```
,,,
  DetailsView(model: item)
    .environmentObject(model)
,,,
```

[Here is a fully working demo](https://gist.github.com/MojtabaHs/bec7588eced25e1a0452b09ba251a65a)

Comment: Thanks! That works and makes sense. It still bothers me a little though, since the whole idea of Model/View or MVVM paradigm is "the view is a function of the model", which means, no action with side effects should be needed.

Comment: It very depends on the context you are working on, you can give the responsibility to the parent as the `NavigationLink` has a mechanism to give the control of the activeness state to the caller. There are also bunch of other ways to handle that as well.

Answer (score 0):

In this case the `ForEach` will no longer have the item and a `NavigationLink` will not be generated and when SwiftUI diffs this body it will remove the list row and also deactivate the old navigation link and will pop the view automatically.

If you don't get this behaviour then try a newer `NavigationLink` API like the value one.

Comment: The ForEach has no problem creating a new list. My problem is that, if the details view is on the top of the navigation stack when the model of that view is removed from `mainModel.items`, the view doesn't know.

Comment: That's strange all of the `View` structs that have `@EnvironmentObject var mainModel` should have their `body` recomputed when the items change.

Comment: Well, a detailed view is associated with a item model, not the main model that contains a list of item models. So, once it's created, it doesn't really know when its model is removed from the list. The item model is not destroyed, after all. So I'm not surprised.
But I really think there should be a mechanism to not just remove the model from the list, but also destroy/garbage collect the object itself, and all views using that model would also destroy themselves.

Comment: @DelingRen usually there is just one model object